# Says wrong username/or passord when trying to login to Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just tried logging in with my usual email and password as I always do. Now all of the sudden it doesn't work. Says Wrong username/or password. What now? anyone else with this issue???? Help

Comment: Not a duplicate imo because the other question is about it not working right from the start due to user error/ambiguous names for the text fields, while in this case, it worked for a while, but doesn't work any more.

Answer (score -2):

Don't panic, I would recommend going to Minecraft's official website and changing your password, all you need is the email you usually use to log in, don't worry about remembering this new password, just insert your old one and put something easy like the number one after it so it's easy to remember. Good luck!